# What is the fastest way to get from Newark Airport to Penn Station, New York? (Excluding cabs)

Tags: usa, public-transport, airports, new-york-city, ewr

It seems like a cab would be the fastest way, but traffic could potentially screw this up, so what's the fastest train route?

Comment: It's a gamble either way.  If there's little traffic, a cab or Uber/Lyft would be faster than a train. What is the scheduled arrival time at EWR?

Answer (score 6):

You don't have much in terms of options there is [The Northeast Corridor](http://www.njtransit.com/pdf/rail/R0070.pdf) line and the [NJ Coast Line](http://www.njtransit.com/pdf/rail/R0080.pdf) of [NJ Transit](http://www.njtransit.com/) that service the Newark Airport and [Amtrak's](http://www.amtrak.com/) Northeast Regional.  The best possible one is NJ Transit since it runs more often and the only possible difference between the 2 is possibility of a single 2 minute stop in Secaucus.

Of course the other option would be to catch a cab or a bus to Newark Penn Station and then you get many many options such as practically every line of [NJ Transit](http://www.njtransit.com/), [AmTrak](http://www.amtrak.com/), and also [PATH](http://www.panynj.gov/path/) which gets you to 33rd and 6th which is 1 block away from the Penn Station.

Personally I prefer the bus which goes to [Port Authority $15 every 15 minutes](http://coachusa1.reachlocal.net/olympia/ss.newarkairport.asp).   Which normally would take 30 and in the worst case in my experience 45 minutes to get from Newark to Port. But choice is ultimately yours.

Comment: I'm catching a train at Penn Station.  Are the PATH trains any faster than NJ transit?

Comment: How long between arrival and the train?  Ultimately you never know since there have been several issues in the last month one of which delayed all trains for over an hour.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to catch Acela? Or are you going to LI?

Comment: I'm trying to catch the Acela at 1pm.  I'm dropping a rental car off at Newark at 11, which I'm assuming will be done at 11:30.

Comment: @Zach Why not just catch Acela out of Newark Penn instead?  Train #2160 leaves Newark at 12:30pm.  And Newark Penn is at most from what I drove 15-20 minutes away from the airport.

Comment: @Zach: PATH trains would be a great deal slower. It's a crowded subway-type train and you need two of them to get to Newark Penn Station. From there, you need to take another train (NJ Transit) for one stop to get to the Newark Airport station.  Why not take NJ Transit from NY Penn straight to EWR?

Comment: @Kanadsky Right idea, wrong direction.  And the ultimate destination is actually Acela,

Comment: @Karlson: all trains go in both directions. You're not suggesting that NJ Transit from EWR to Newark/Penn Station, change to PATH, then change to another PATH train at Journal Square and ride it 7 stops to the 33rd street -- that all that would be better than a 3-stop straight shot on NJ Transit, are you?

Comment: @Kanadsky Given that Acela is the ultimate destination I was suggesting not going to NY Penn Station at all.  Noone suggests using PATH instead of NJ Transit and I know that Trains go in both directions but the direction OP is interested in is EWR to Penn Station not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

[**NJ Transit**](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=AirportConnectionsTo) is the most straightforward way.  Several trains every hour depart and arrive at NY Penn Station and the third stop from NY Penn station is the Newark Liberty Airport (EWR).  The trip takes a bit less than 30 minutes, it is very predictable as you don't depend on traffic, and it and costs $12.50 one-way.

Comment: Wrong direction.

Comment: @Karlson: I said both arrive and depart (at NY Penn). The trains go in both directions.  So, as the OP wants to go from EWR to NY Penn station, this is the train.