# New York City from Newark airport

Tags: airport-transfer, new-york-city, ewr

I am a small town country girl traveling to NYC alone for the first time. I will be arriving at the Newark airport.

How do I get to Manhattan from there?

What is the best mode of transportation?

Comment: We've had a few questions on this, but it's impossible to answer without knowing where in Manhattan you're going and what your preferences are. Speed? Cost? Simplicity? Luxury? What time of day will you be traveling?

Comment: I think the questions http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-from-newark-airport-to-penn-station-new-york-e and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37342/options-to-from-from-newark-nj-airport-and-penn-station-ny-at-6pm-and-10am cover most of the options.  My impression is that most people take the NJ Transit train.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. As noted, there isn't one single "best" way for all people, which is why multiple options exist. For an overview of those options, in the U.S., the most common term you want to look for on an airport's website is *ground transportation* for all the ways to get to and from an airport, and thus the  [Newark Liberty International Airport Ground Transportation](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-ground-transportation.html) page.

Comment: Is there a budget to consider?

Comment: The OP will be lost in the hustle and bustle of EWR, How to recognize the right train to take? How to know the taxi is safe? Are there safe gypsies that could be cheaper? There's also incredibly cheap choppers into Manhattan.

Comment: @special_teacher in answer to your specific question ("I am a small town country girl traveling to NYC alone for the first time"), the specific answer is: take a taxi.

Comment: Simple: https://goo.gl/maps/yeGw3VWmpik.

Answer (score 7):

There is a large variety of options for travel from Newark Airport to Manhattan. I have assumed you're travelling to the Port Authority Bus Terminal (as per the bounty), a short walk from Times Square. I have listed them below in **decreasing order of both convenience and price**.

1. Take a direct taxi - [$55 plus tip](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/ewr-taxi-car-van-service.html), tolls ($8-10), baggage fees and a $5 rush-hour fee. Count on **~$70-$80** all in.
2. A shared van service, for example [Supershuttle](https://www.supershuttle.com). They pick you and a bunch of other passengers up and drop you each off at your own destination. **$23** each way
3. Take the [Newark Airport Express bus](https://newarkairportexpress.com/Newark/Home). Departs directly outside each terminal on level 1. **$16** one-way, or $28 round trip. This goes straight to the aforementioned Port Authority Bus Terminal
4. [The NJ Transit Train](http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=AirportConnectionsTo). Follow signs to the AirTrain on arrival and buy a ticket to Penn station. There is one change of train, from the airport monorail to a "proper" train. **$13** each way. This lands you at New York Penn Station which is a 10-minute walk from the bus terminal or Times Square.

The following two solutions are included for completeness; I doubt they'd be suitable for yourself.

4. Take the #62 bus to Newark Penn Station ($1.60, exact change), and change for the NJ Transit Train (the same one as you'd take from the Airport, but for a lower fare) heading for Penn Station for $5.25. Total cost of **$6.85**.
5. Take the same bus to Newark Penn Station, buy a Pay-Per-Ride Metrocard with $10 credit on it from one of the PATH vending machines and use same to travel on the PATH train to World Trade Center, changing there for the Subway A or C train to "42 Street - Port Authority Bus Terminal" Station. Note that this is a reusable card valid for the Subway and NYC buses, and $10 is exactly enough for a round trip from the Newark Penn Station to any New York Subway station. You may wish to add more if you intend to use the Subway during your stay. Total cost of **$6.60**, not including the one-off card fee of $1.

Answer (score 3):

If your destination is lower Manhattan, you can take the New Jersey Transit bus to Newark Penn Station and then take the PATH train from there to the World Trade Center. This is especially attractive if you have a relatively small amount of luggage, as the total fare is around $6, but it involves carrying your luggage around.

It is also possible to change to a different PATH train that will take you to Christopher Street or to any of four stations on Sixth Avenue between 9th and 33rd Streets.

Comment: I would not recommend this for "small town country girl".

Answer (score 3):

My experience was to be met by a stretched limo with a local driver (Mitch) - I recommend it, best I know of.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options:

- By rail. Read more about it on NJ Transit official website http://www.njtransit.com/rg/rg_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=AirportConnectionsTo
- By bus. I think it costs around $20-25. You can always ask at Information Desk at the airport where the bus stops and how much is it.
- By taxi. They have flat fee. Probably around $50-70 depends what part of Manhattan you are going to. Don't forget tolls and tips.

Comment: http://www.panynj.gov/airports/pdf/ewr-airtrain-brochure-english.pdf that's the map where it shows how to connect to the rail. Taxi is outside of any terminal. You won't need any guidance to see where to get taxi. Talking about buses - it's better to ask at Help Desk.

Comment: Taking a Newark taxi from outside the terminal will run more like $90, because the driver is entitled to the tolls reimbursed, both ways. And a tip. And much, much more if stuck in traffic. A much better idea is to pre-book a car service (e.g., [Carmel](https://www.carmellimo.com), with which I have no affiliation) at a flat rate. Having said that, I would suggest the train unless the destination is too far from rail access or the OP has too much luggage.

Answer (score 1):

An economical and convenient way to get to the Port Authority bus terminal in Midtown Manhattan is to take the AirTrain Newark (a monorail) to the airport railway station, and from there catch an NJ Transit commuter train to New York Penn Station, from where it is a single subway stop (line A, C or E) to Port Authority terminal.

This route will take roughly 50 minutes and cost 15.75 dollars in total.

There are also [direct buses](https://newarkairportexpress.com/Newark/Home) from the airport to the Port Authority terminal, which cost USD 17. However, be warned that congestions on this road, as in much of urban America, can be disastrous and lead to a very long travel time unless buses have dedicated lanes on the road from Newark to New York.

Comment: I personally prefer the bus to the train. The bus departs directly from a stop next to the terminal, so you don’t have to take the AirTrain first. You can store your luggage in the hold of the bus, avoiding the need to fit it in sometimes cramped NJ Transit trains with suitcases. The bus makes multiple stops in Midtown Manhattan, not just Port Authority, and you don’t have to navigate the very confusing Penn Station at the end. The buses do not have a dedicated lane, but I have not experienced excessive delays even in rush hour.